# How do I simplify a Multivariable expression involving derivatives of logarithms?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, logarithms

I have this expression I got after a lot of calculation:

$$\sigma =\frac{d\log\left(\frac{b(x,y,\rho)}{r(x,y,\rho)}\right)}{d\log\left(\frac{
2 }{3}\left(\frac{b(x,y,\rho)}{r(x,y,\rho)}\right)^{-\rho-1}\right)}$$

I know $$[\log(f)]' = \frac{f'}{f}$$ but the problem is, I am uncertain how to handle this since $b$ and $r$ are multivariable.

**My Question**

I want to simplify the logs. Will applying total derivatives help somehow? Or am I overlooking some obvious simplification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u= \log\frac{b(x,y,\rho)}{r(x,y,\rho)}$, so that $\log\left(\frac{
2 }{3}\left(\frac{b(x,y,\rho)}{r(x,y,\rho)}\right)^{-\rho-1}\right)=\log\frac{2}{3} - (\rho +1)u.$

Then,

$$\sigma =\frac{d u}{d\left[\log\frac{2}{3} - (\rho +1)u\right]} =\frac{-1}{\rho+1}.$$

Comment: Brilliant. I was completely baffled. Now it all makes sense.

Comment: I should note that this works because $\log\frac{2}{3} - (\rho +1)u$ is invertible, so we have $du/df = 1\Big/(df/du)$.

Comment: One thing that confused me: why do we put $d$ next to the log? I thought that meant differential....which meant infinitesimal...what does the $d$ signify here? Is $du$ a differential? I always assumed infinitesimals involved variables not functions. But maybe there is no difference?

Comment: What is the variable $u$ than just the linear function $f(u)=u$? :-) $\mathrm{d}u$ is a differential, and so is $\mathrm{d}f(u)$. When we have $\mathrm{d}[(f\circ g)(x))]/\mathrm{d}x$, we ask ourselves "how quick is $f\circ g$ changing with respect to $x$?" When we have $\mathrm{d}[(f\circ g)(x)]/\mathrm{d}[g(x)]$, we ask ourselves "how quick is $f\circ g$ changing with respect to $g(x)$?"

Comment: It's similar to how we perform $u$ substitutions to simplify integrals.

To simplify $\int \cos(2x) dx$, we substitute $u=2x$. Or, we can recognize that
$$\int \cos(2x) dx = \frac{1}{2} \int \cos(2x) d[2x],$$
which gives us the same outcome.

Comment: Ohhhhh, that's clever! A nice analogy. I remember that now. I had forgotten you could do that. So then, for $\mathrm{d}[(f\circ g)]/\mathrm{d}[g(x)]$, is this like asking $\mathrm{d}f(u)/\mathrm{d}u$? Yes. I assume that's the point.

Comment: Pretty much! It gets tricky when we have $\mathrm{d}f(x)/\mathrm{d}g(x)$ though, as the relation between $f$ and $g$ may not be evident.

Comment: For example? What do you mean by not as evident?

Comment: Well just like in your question, when we made the substitution for $u=\log\frac{b}{r}$, we couldn't immediately stick $u$ into the denominator differential. We had to first consider $e^u=\frac{b}{r}$, which can be substituted for something in the denominator.

Comment: That's awesome. I had no idea I would learn this much asking this question :D